# Is it possible to detect text-width with pure css?

Tags: css, percentage, relation, text-width, window-width

I would like to know how much percent width a sentence (in relation to window width) have.

**Example:**

Given:

1. Sentence with 20 letters including white space
2. Font Arial, font-size 20px

Wanted:

Width of the text (without wrap) in percentage in any resolution

Comment: No text width is not a css property or value. Font size is a text height value

Comment: you should consider the fact that each character has its own width so what you want is impossible unsless you know the exact text or you consider a monospace font where the width is 20ch

Comment: Thank you @TemaniAfif, I just wanted to be sure.